# primefaces 3.5 selectonemenu doesn't display data

Tags: primefaces, selectonemenu

since two days I am facing strange issue with PrimeFaces 3.5 selectOneMenu object. 
I am working in this architecture JPA + EJB + JAX-WS in an EJB project and I create a client from the JAX-WS service in a Web Project. The Web Service Client is then encapsulated in a ManagedBean to be bind with my PrimeFaces interface.
My ManagedBean is the following :

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;
import tg.moov.imereport.service.DownStream;
import tg.moov.imereport.service.DownStreamWSService;


@Named
@Stateless
public class DownStreamMBean {
    private DownStreamWSService service;

    public DownStreamMBean() {
        service = new DownStreamWSService();
    }

    public List<DownStream> getDownStreamsService() {
        return service.getDownStreamWSPort().getDownStreams();
    }

}
```

and the selectOneMenu code is the following :

```
<h:form>
  <p:selectOneMenu value="#{downStreamTotalMBean.ds.IDDownStream}"> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{downStreamMBean.downStreamsService}" var="item"
      itemValue="#{item.IDDownStream}" itemLabel="#{item.nom}"/>                         
  </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Here is the DownStream class :

```
package tg.moov.imereport.service;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for downStream complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="downStream">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="IDDownStream" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="IPAddress" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="login" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="nom" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="password" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="path" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "downStream", propOrder = {
    "idDownStream",
    "ipAddress",
    "login",
    "nom",
    "password",
    "path"
})
public class DownStream {

    @XmlElement(name = "IDDownStream")
    protected String idDownStream;
    @XmlElement(name = "IPAddress")
    protected String ipAddress;
    protected String login;
    protected String nom;
    protected String password;
    protected String path;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the idDownStream property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getIDDownStream() {
        return idDownStream;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the idDownStream property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setIDDownStream(String value) {
        this.idDownStream = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the ipAddress property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getIPAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the ipAddress property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setIPAddress(String value) {
        this.ipAddress = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the login property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the login property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setLogin(String value) {
        this.login = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the nom property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the nom property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setNom(String value) {
        this.nom = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the password property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the password property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setPassword(String value) {
        this.password = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the path property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the path property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setPath(String value) {
        this.path = value;
    }

}
```

The web service is working correctly and display data, but the selectOneMenu does not show anything.
Please can some one help me. I can provide more information if needed.

Regards.

Comment: could you post tg.moov.imereport.service.DownStream ? I am wondering what the toString implementation looks like of that class(if it has been overwritten)

Comment: I just updated my first post with the DownStream JPA class. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry it is the DownStream coming from tg.moov.imereport.service.

Comment: Are you sure you getting data to getDownStreamsService() ? Tested without converter, but it works too.

Comment: can be something wrong with stateless?

Comment: I test the web service and I am able to retrieve Data. It should normaly work when called from the client. I am also suspecting the annotation I am using. Because all my beans are stateless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a converter for your custom class on the selectOneMenu.

See BalusC his explanation here [objects in selectonemenu](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html)

in primefaces the `<p:selectOneMenu>` has a `converter=""`  attribute which you can use to link the converter too instead of having to add it seperatly using `<f:converter>`

Comment: Thank for your feedback. In my case as the `item.nom` is a String, I guess I don't need to use the `converter=""` attribute. I will try it and come back to you.

Comment: I am suspecting my beans annotations. But it seems like everything is correct.

Comment: could you add a `<p:messages />` and see if it displays any errors?

Comment: Finaly it works, but I don't really know what how. The only thing I have done is to change the PrimeFaces version from 3.5 to 3.2. Thank to everyone.